# LinkedList and pointers confusion

Tags: java, pointers, linked-list

i am working with linked list,and I have one possibly stupid question.I have class Node for linked list which contains attribute Node as next element,and I have this line:

```
Node current=head;
while(current!=null)
current=current.next;
```

I don't understand why head doesn't also change,but only current?And why does it change only if I do `current.next=current.next.next`,how can that reflect anyhow on head?I understand that with `current=current.next` we iterate through current(head),and it changes current,but why doesn't it change head also?Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're confused between mutating a variable and mutating an object.

Comment: aha,`a` and `b` here are objects,and head is variable..but why then `current.next=current.next.next` change head??when head is not changed with `current=current.next`?do you know maybe?

Comment: It might help you understand this to draw this on paper. Each `Node` instance is a box, and each variable (`current`, `head`, `next`) is an arrow pointing to some `Node` (or nothing for `null`).